How to pass dynamic meta data along with fromJson()?
I have a problem for which I am sure there is a solution. I just can't find it.
I am parsing a Json using moshi. Some custom adapters have to filter/transform the data based on some meta data that might change for every single fromJson() call.
So I need a way to pass this information along with fromJson() into a custom adapter - lets say "call context" information. Any idea how to do that?
Here is an example: let's assume I have a parse() method which gets called every time with a different second parameter callContext: CallContextInfo):
private val adapter: JsonAdapter<Foobar> =
    Moshi.Builder()
        .add(MyCustomAdapter())
        .build()
        .adapter(Foobar::class.java)

fun parse(json: String, callContext: CallContextInfo): Foobar? =
    adapter.fromJson(json)

My custom adapter should filter the values of a list based on this second parameter:
internal class MyCustomAdapter {
    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(list: List<String>): List<String> =
        list.filter { /* use CallContextInfo for filtering */ }
}

So I need a way to pass this context information into my custom adapter. I don't want to store that information somewhere else as the parse method might be called from multiple threads in parallel.

sounds like you'll want a JsonAdapter.Factory, but I can't tell exactly from your description. Can you give a concrete example with code?
